# How to display footer.html at the index.html?

Tags: iframe, integration, display, google-web-designer

I am new programmer and I follow the project created by others.

The programmer writes < footer>< /footer> at the index.html.

Then the footer.html has been shown at the index.html.

I have no idea how can he do that.

For more information, the project includes html, css, javascript, php, angular.

Please let me know how to customize new tag and show the page using the tag rather

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLeV0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9OdA.png)

Comment: Can you please show the code that was used there?  That will help us help you better.

Comment: I have upload two pictures about my code.
As you can see, it just use <footer></footer> to show the footer.page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.

The answer is angular.

myapp.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
.directive('footer',function(){
    return { 
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl:'include/footer.html'
    }
})
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<footer></footer>
```